# The output of the recursive function is coming out to be wrong , i cant find any mistake in the code

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming

The purpose of the function is to find the numbers in a given array can form the given sum or not. It can use the numbers in the array as many times as required to get the sum. Can anyone find the the flaw in the logic. I am using recursion to solve the problem

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

bool findsum(int targetsum , vector<int> arr)
{
    if(targetsum == 0)
        { return true;
        }
    
    
    if(targetsum < 0)
        { return false;
        }
        
    for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
            int rem = targetsum - arr[i];
            if (findsum(rem,arr) == true);
            {
                return true;
            }
        
    }
    
    return false;
}





int main()
{
    int a = 4;
    vector<int> array{5};
    cout << findsum(a,array);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `if (findsum(rem,arr) == true)` should be written `if (findsum(rem,arr))`.

Comment: either of them can be used right?

Comment: They both mean the same thing. Just like `if (i == 0)` means the same thing as `if ((i == 0) == true)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a semicolon after the if statement. That signifies the end of the if statement.

```
if (findsum(rem,arr) == true);
{
    return true;
}
```

The code above returns true regardless of the value of the condition.
This mistake is common enough that modern compilers will warn you if you turn warnings on, which you should.

Comment: thx it worked, I was scratching my head for a long time thinking that my logic was wrong. I was using dev c++ , I will make sure that I turn warnings on next time